# Random Colour Schemes with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a website that requires different elements to be styled with a main base colour and multiple associated accented analogic colours randomly. For example, the user gets a colour wheel to select the base colour and based on that input the jquery would then apply a colour scheme based on that input colour. Is this possible at all with jquery? I'm happy to implement this with php if required.

If you need a better clarification of what I'm trying to achieve image [this](http://colorschemedesigner.com/#5561Tw0w0w0w0). Where the colour scheme is created automatically.

Comment: Sure, using RGB you could just make lighter/darker versions of whatever color is selected, and apply them to different elements. A "one solution fits all" is probably not easy to come by, and you will have to write this to fit your site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're basically asking for an "API" or lower-level description of how to build complementary colors, in the way that those color-scheme sites illustrate.  For your application, to start with I'd take a look here (for example) on manipulating RGB hex strings:  http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/.  And then here on the theory/math behind calculating complementary colors:  http://www.webmaster-forums.net/web-design-and-graphics/color-theory-calculating-complementary-colors.